# React + StyledComponent + Tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, tailwind-css

**Hi **Everyone**!**

Just wondering how can I implement this combination in my React Project or is there any better workflow for beginner?

I thought StyledComponent will be able to parse something like this:

```
export const sample = styled.div`
    @apply bg-gray-500 w-full h-24
`;
```

Since this works by importing style.css class:

```
.sample{
    @apply bg-gray-500 w-full h-24
}
```

I understand that this might be due to css preprocessor under the hood from my dependencies but, may I ask how can I do this with my current setup?

Comment: I suppose this should do the trick <Sample className="classNameForTailwindStyles"></Sample>

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I am trying to do is to enable styled-component understand that I am using tailwind classnames which what I tried to do in the ```styled.div``

Comment: I guess that won't be possible..all styled component does is that it adds a classname to the div based on the styles and inject those styles in the <styles> tag in the DOM. I suppose it could be possible if you modify the source code of styled-components

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is **twin.macro**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/twin.macro

Basically in order to be able to use tailwind features inside a styled component you need to "tell babel to compile them together".

You can look for some tutorial in order to do so but that's the short story.

It has many other features you will see in the documentation.

Tip: Install "Tailwind Twin IntelliSense" extension in VSCode if you are using it.

Example of use:

```
const H1 = styled.h1`
  ${tw`text-center border-4 long_class long_class`}
  ${tw`continue_long_class_in_new_line`}
  color: red;
  more custom styles here...`
```